# Create set of rules with one flag variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code which goes like this:

```
flag = 0
if A == 'string1':
    flag = 1
if B == 'string2':
    flag = 1
if C == 'string3':
    flag = 1
```

Is there a way to create a list of the rules I want to check, check whether at least one is true, and set `flag` to 1?  For example,

```
D = [A == 'string1', B == 'string2', C=='string3']
if D:
    flag = 1
```

Comment: You could make a function similar to what you have if what you want is reusability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there.

```
D = [A == 'string1', B == 'string2', C=='string3']
if True in D:
    flag = 1
```

D has the boolean values of each test, True in D tests if any of them are True.

Edit: I wrote this over a year ago, but someone upvoted it recently, and looking back at it, I now know there is a built in that saves a few keystrokes.

We can write the code above as

```
D = [A == 'string1', B == 'string2', C=='string3']
if any(D):
    flag = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if A == 'string1' or \
   B == 'string2' or \
   C == 'string3':
    flag = True    # use Boolean values, not coded numbers
```

Or simply assign the result of the Boolean expression:

```
flag = A == 'string1' or \
       B == 'string2' or \
       C == 'string3'
```

This last one will give `flag` the proper value, either `True` or `False`.

---

If you need a list of variables and values, try something like this:

```
vars = [A, B, C]
vals = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
flag = any([vars[i] == vals[i] for i in range(len(vars)) ])
```

... or make a dictionary of those same items (courtesy of `codehearts`):

```
checks = { 'string1': A, 'string2': B, 'string3': C }
flag = any([var == val for var, val in checks.iteritems() ])
```

... or `zip` the list into pairs (tuples) per `wwii`:

```
flag = any(a == b for a, b in zip(vars, vals))
```

You can extend the list sizes as far as you want.  This assumes that each "rule" is simply checking paired values.

Comment: This can be adjusted to let `flag = 1` occur, on the condition a `1 and ` and a set of parentheses is added to this :)

Comment: ```any(a == b for a, b in zip(vars, vals))```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **any**:

```
if any((A == 'string1', B == 'string2', C=='string3')):
    flag = 1
```

Comment: Gotta wrap those in a list

Comment: even simpler  `flag = any((A=="str1", B=="str2", C=="str3"))`

Comment: well, as @Rawing mentioned before, "OP asked for the flag to equal 1, not True" (but i'm 99% sure you are right and boolean will match OP's code better =)

Comment: well what about `flag = int(any((A=="str1", B=="str2", C=="str3")))`

Comment: @rth i cannot argue against BDFL
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/
so your code is correct